# How to create a bipartite network in R with igraph or tnet

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I have an edgelist for a two mode network, similar to this:

```
person  Event
Amy     football_game
Sam     picnic
Bob     art_show
```

I want to perform an analysis on this in R, but seemingly everything I try fails. Converting it to a one mode network runs into memory limitations, and I can't figure out how to analyze it as bipartite in either igraph or tnet.

In igraph, `bipartite.projection` gives me all `FALSE`, on the igraph object created using

```
net <- graph.edgelist(myobject)
```

On tnet, I can't convert the igraph net to a tnet one, and when I try to use the original data frame, it refuses because of duplicates in the graph.

So answers to any of the following would be super appreciated:

1. How do I use the `bipartite.mapping` function?
2. How do I input an igraph object into tnet?
3. If all else fails, how I do I input a data frame with duplicate edges into tnet?

Sorry if these are basic questions, but there's very little documentation.

### EDIT

Example:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text="Person    Event
                             Amy       football
                             Bob       picnic
                             Sam       artshow", 
                       header=TRUE)
edgelist <- as.matrix(edgelist)

## Igraph Issues
igraph <- graph.edgelist(edgelist)
typevector <- bipartite.projection(igraph) 
# gets all FALSE

edgelist2 <- get.edgelist(igraph)
typevector <- bipartite.projection(edgelist2) 
# same thing

## tnet issues
tnet <- as.tnet(edgelist) 
# gives error: "There are duplicate events in the edgelist"
tnet <- as.tnet(edgelist2)
clusterMat <- clustering_local_tm(tnet)  
# gives error: "max not meaningful for factors"

onemode <- projecting_tm(tnet, method="Newman") 
# gives error: "arguments must have same length"
```

Comment: Always try to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381). It will help a lot. We have no idea what `myobject` are.

Comment: Also, if anyone just has a tutorial or an example of tnet, that alone could help a lot.

Comment: @user1888451 Tore Opsahl (the author) works through some examples on his website. http://toreopsahl.com/tnet/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In igraph a bipartite network is one that has a `type` vertex attribute. This attribute must be logical and must the `TRUE` for one of the node types and `FALSE` for the others. So to create a bipartite network from your edge list, you simply create a regular graph and then add the `type` vertex attribute:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text="Person    Event
                         Amy       football
                         Bob       picnic
                         Sam       artshow", 
                   header=TRUE)
igraph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)

V(igraph)$type <- V(igraph)$name %in% edgelist[,1]
igraph
# IGRAPH DN-B 6 3 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), type (v/x)
```

The 'B' letter tells you that this is a bipartite graph. You can create the unipartite projections of this network via:

```
bipartite.projection(igraph)
# $proj1
# IGRAPH UN-B 3 0 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), type (v/x)
#
# $proj2
# IGRAPH UN-B 3 0 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), type (v/x)
```

This will return a list of two graphs. If you think that the projection might be too big, you can first call the `bipartite.projection.size` function, this will give you the number of vertices and edges in both projections. The memory requirement for an igraph graph is (4m+2n)*8+O(1) bytes, where 'n' is the number of vertices and 'm' is the number of edges.

Comment: @Gabor i was trying to project a weighted biparite graph and i get the error negative vectors not allowed which crashes my R session...have you had this before?

Comment: @user1317221_G: most likely your graph is not bipartite, i.e. you have connections between vertices of the same type.

Comment: @Gabor Can you please tell how to visualize that graph. with two different kinds of nodes with different colors

Comment: Set vertex color based on vertex type, e.g. `V(g)$color <- V(g)$type + 1`.

Comment: "The memory requirement for an igraph graph is (4m+2n)*8+O(1) byte"  What does O(1) mean in this equation?

Comment: @Zach Constant amount, independent of the number of vertices and edges.