# How can I get a new graph translating the vertices to categories of vertices?

Tags: r, igraph

I am not sure of how to phrase this question, which is making it very hard to find a solution.

I have a graph of people and their relationships in igraph. I also have the location of this people in a dataframe.

```
> # graph.id is their id in the graph
> people
    user.name   graph.id    location.cell
1   perez       654         54
2   garcia      123         54
3   fernandez   771         32
4   rodriguez   11          81
```

My graph connects users by their graph.id:

```
user 654 <-> user 11
user 123 <-> user 11
```

And I want a new graph with their regions, with a

```
cell 54 <- weight 2-> cell 81

(there are two connections between cells 54 and 81, 
 one between users 11 and 654, 
 and another between users 11 and 123,
 so weight=2)
```

How can I do this in R (I'm using igraph)? I've tried a couple of times, iterating over the edges in the graph, but I ended up with too much code that wasn't going to be acceptably fast or mantainable, and it doesn't look like a problem that should be hard (I think I wouldn't have any problem to do this kind of thing in a language I was more comfortable with).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before I do this as a flag (only for SO housekeeping) is this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367779/how-to-create-a-bipartite-network-in-r-with-igraph-or-tnet - close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am not sure.. but looks promising. I'll read through it more carefully and try it. If it is, I'll flag or remove the question mysef. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `graph.data.frame` function in `igraph`, creating a new graph based on the region associated with each edge in your current graph.

First, here's the setup you're describing:

```
# 654 <-> 11; 123 <-> 11; 123 <-> 771
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(cbind(c(654, 123, 123), c(11, 11, 771)))
people <- data.frame(graph.id=c(654, 123, 771, 11), location.cell=c(54, 54, 32, 81))
```

Now you can store the location of each vertex within `g` and use that vertex attribute to grab the location of each edge endpoint:

```
V(g)$location <- people$location.cell[match(V(g)$name, people$graph.id)]
g2 <- graph.data.frame(cbind(V(g)$location[get.edges(g, E(g))[,1]],
                             V(g)$location[get.edges(g, E(g))[,2]]), directed=F)
E(g2)
# str(g2)
# IGRAPH UN-- 3 3 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] 54--81 54--81 54--32
```

To convert multiple edges to a single edge with higher weight, you can use `simplify`:

```
E(g2)$weight <- 1
g2 <- simplify(g2)
str(g2)
# IGRAPH UNW- 3 2 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] 54--81 54--32
E(g2)$weight
# [1] 2 1
```