# Transform ids -> items to {pairs of ids} -> items

Tags: r, dataframe

### I have a data.frame like this:

```
x1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,item=c("A","B","A","B","C","D"))
x1[order(x1$item),]
  id item
1  1    A
3  3    A
2  2    B
4  1    B
5  2    C
6  3    D
```

## I want to get :

```
id1=c(1,2,1,3,2,3)
id2 = c(2,1,3,1,3,2)
A=c(0,0,1,1,0,0)
B=c(1,1,0,0,0,0)
C = 0
D=0
datawanted <- data.frame(id1,id2,A,B,C,D)
  id1 id2 A B C D
1   1   2 0 1 0 0
2   2   1 0 1 0 0
3   1   3 1 0 0 0
4   3   1 1 0 0 0
5   2   3 0 0 0 0
6   3   2 0 0 0 0
```

if person1 and person2 both have B,then in the **datawanted** dataframe,column A ,got 1,else get 0.

Can someone give me some suggestions or functions in R,to deal with this problem?

Comment: what is the logic for id2?

Comment: id2 is the same as id1, person1 and person2 have a contact on B,just like it.

Comment: What is the logic for rows 5 and 6 of `datawanted`?

Comment: person2 and person3 do not hava a contact,so it indicates zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool question. You have a bipartite graph, so following [Gabor's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393156/)...

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(x1))
V(g)$type = grepl("[A-Z]", V(g)$name)
```

For OP's desired output, first we can extract the incidence matrix:

```
gi = get.incidence(g)
#   A B C D
# 1 1 1 0 0
# 2 0 1 1 0
# 3 1 0 0 1
```

Note (thanks @thelatemail), that if you don't want to use igraph, you can get to `gi` as `table(x1)`.

Then, we look at the combinations of ids:

```
res = t(combn(nrow(gi), 2, function(x) c(
    as.integer(rownames(gi)[x]), 
    pmin( gi[x[1], ], gi[x[2], ] ) 
)))

dimnames(res) <- list( NULL, c("id1", "id2", colnames(gi)))
#      id1 id2 A B C D
# [1,]   1   2 0 1 0 0
# [2,]   1   3 1 0 0 0
# [3,]   2   3 0 0 0 0
```

This essentially is the OP's desired output. They had included redundant rows (e.g., 1,2 and 2,1).

---

Fun reason to use a graph ([ht Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31375966/)):

```
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "red", "light blue")
V(g)$x     <- (1:2)[ V(g)$type + 1 ]
V(g)$y     <- ave(seq_along(V(g)), V(g)$type, FUN = seq_along)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Or, apparently this can be done more or less like

```
plot(g, layout = layout.bipartite(g)[,2:1])
```

Comment: Isn't the first part of this just `table(x1)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Sure, but it's a graph, so might as well store it as one. If the OP isn't done with their analysis after this, they might take advantage of whatever other tools igraph has (... though I'm not that familiar with them myself). Good point, though, I've edited to reflect it.

Comment: thanks,if id changes like c(1,3,4),and the method you give may cause subscript outbounding.
`combn` and pmin did give me some help.I need to think about if the id is not corrospended with rownumbers,and how can it work?

Comment: I use the code like this ,should this cause any question?

`res[,1] <- x1$id[res[,1]]`
`res[,2] <- x1$id[res[,2]]`

Comment: @chunjin Good catch. Yes, I think your way works. I've also edited to show a different way above, changing the construction of `res` to use `as.integer(rownames(gi)[x])` instead of `x`.