# How to construct bipartite graphs using igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I need to create a bipartite graph for consumer-brand relationships.

This is my example data:

```
datf <- data.frame(Consumers = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                   Brands = c("Costa", "Starbucks", "Cafe2U", "Costa", "Costa"))
```

The following code gives me a network. But I am not sure how I can add a node type attribute to label consumers and brands:

```
    library(igraph) 
    dat=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE) 
    el=as.matrix(dat) 
    el[,1]=as.character(el[,1])
    el[,2]=as.character(el[,2])
    g=graph.edgelist(el,directed=FALSE)
```

I would like to create a bipartite graph with edges that connect each consumer with the brand they like. Ideally, the nodes will be labeled with text.

Could you show me how to do this using `library(igraph)`?

Comment: what `library(igraph)` code have you tried?

Comment: Hi Nate, I read the file in gephi (with two columns- consumers and brands) and exported a graphml file read it igraph. However, that doesn't add the vertext type. I'm trying to visualize brands and consumers in different colors and calculate the interaction between brands and conumers.

Comment: that sounds like you are really close to your desired output, it's always good to include the code you have with your questions. That way people are more likely to help and can provide feedback tailored to your current situation

Comment: This is a code I used to create a similar network.############## library(igraph) 
dat=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE) #################### (data looks like this   Consumer     Brand
1     John     Costa
2     Jack     Costa
3    Wendy Starbucks
4   Alfred    Cafe2U
5     Noah  Stabucks) ##############################
el=as.matrix(dat) 
el[,1]=as.character(el[,1])
el[,2]=as.character(el[,2])
g=graph.edgelist(el,directed=FALSE)########### This works, but I can't figure out a way to assign attributes/labels (consumers and brands)

Comment: `mi_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(datf); plot(mi_graph)` gets you a labeled graph. I think you can search SO and find [how to add colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph)

Comment: Thanks very much @Nate. I really appreciate your quick reply. This works fine. And also, is there a way to create a extra node type attribute so that all the people are given the category of "consumers" and all coffee brands and given the category "coffee"?

Comment: if you want the graph to be bipartite, you new to assign a boolean vector to an attribute called “type”—eg `V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% el[,1]`. If you call the graph it should show that it is bipartite—you will see a B after “IGRAPH”

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367779/how-to-create-a-bipartite-network-in-r-with-igraph-or-tnet)

Comment: Thanks @paqmo. That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This resource at [Shizuka Lab](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/bipartite) is really useful for exploring bipartite networks in R with `igraph`. In short:

```
library(igraph)

# Your matrix containing consumer choice by brands
m = matrix(data = sample(0:1, 25, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
colnames(m) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
rownames(m) = c("Costa", "Starbucks", "Cafe2U", "Petes", "Philz")

# Convert it to a bipartitie network
bg = igraph::graph.incidence(m)
bg

# See the vertex attributes 
V(bg)$type 
V(bg)$name

# Plot the network
shape = ifelse(V(bg)$type, "circle", "square") # assign shape by node type
col = ifelse(V(bg)$type, "red", "yellow") # assign color by node type

plot(bg, vertex.shape = shape, vertex.color = col)
```

Gives: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nistara. This is great.

Comment: You're welcome; accept this answer if it worked for you!